# Why doesnt the remove function work here?

Tags: c

I want to scan from an existing savefile, and delete it afterwards so I can create a new savefile of the same name later, however this code doesnt delete anyhthing:

```
void readsave()
{
    FILE* f;
    int prior;  

    fopen_s(&f, "save.txt", "r");
    while (!feof(f))    
    {
        fscanf_s(f, "%d", &prior);
        createNew(prior);
    }
    fclose(f);
    remove("save.txt"); 
}
```

this returns -1 when saved to int:

```
remove("save.txt");
```

Comment: Highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: `remove` sets `errno` when it returns -1; check that for more information.

Comment: include errno.h and call strerror(errno), what does it say?

Comment: It's probably still open by whatever is writing it (which, dependent upon the sharing settings, will allow reading but (of course cannot) allow deleting it.

Comment: errno says Permission denied.. but how can it be open when I call fclose before? using remove(); later in the code (out of readsave) doesnt work either..

Comment: you may have permission to write but no permission to remove that file

Comment: What is your platform? What happens if you put just `remove("save.txt"); ` and nothing else in your `readsave` function, just for testing?

Comment: Couple things to try... Can you delete the file from the command line? Can you delete the file if you send `remove` the entire file path?

Answer (score 1):

While the return value of -1 from `remove` is not exactly helpful in determining why it failed, you can get more detailed information by examining `errno`, which is a designated error-holding variable for various standard library function calls.

The function `perror` will print a string detailing the code in `errno`:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // perror
#include <stdlib.h> // exit, remove
#include <errno.h>  // errno

if(remove("file") == -1)
{
     perror("remove");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: it says remove: Permission denied...perhaps I am supposed to save the file somewhere separately?

Comment: @MancatoIlDottore It could also be that the file can't be deleted since it's still open. Hard to say since your environment is not known to us